# iOS VIMNetworking cannot find file #import "VIMNetworking.h"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, vimeo-ios

I used cocoapods to bring VIMNetworking library into my project.

```
pod 'VIMNetworking', '~> 6.0'

pod 'VIMObjectMapper', '~> 6.0'
```

Now in the AppDelegate.m of my project folder when the pods where installed I try

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "VIMNetworking.h"
```

I receive this error ! "VIMNetworking.h" file not found.

When I search the VIMNetworking Pod for this file it doesn't exist.
I am just trying to follow the initialization setup in gitHub.

```
#import "VIMNetworking.h"

. . .

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    VIMSessionConfiguration *config = [[VIMSessionConfiguration alloc] init];
    config.clientKey = @"your_client_key";
    config.clientSecret = @"your_client_secret";
    config.scope = @"your_scope"; // E.g. "private public upload etc"
    config.keychainService = @"your_service"; 
    config.keychainAccessGroup = @"your_access_group"; // Optional

    [VIMSession sharedSession setupWithConfiguration:config];    

    if ([[VIMSession sharedSession].account isAuthenticated] == NO)
    {
        NSLog(@"Authenticate...");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Already authenticated!");
    }

    . . .
}
```

Thanks for any feedback on how to get the pod initialized into my project.

Comment: hi @Travis Spire-Sweet did you get solution..?

Comment: No, never did.  Moved on to other things.  @SAMIRRATHOD